# Fotorama Reload on AJAX Success Magento 2

Tags: magento2, fotorama

Anyone have idea of the Fotorma Gallery Reload on Product Page on AJAX Success Magento 2. Can anyone help me to guide it?

```
jQuery(".fotorama").empty();
jQuery(".fotorama--hidden").remove();
jQuery('.fotorama').fotorama({
data: image
});
```

Image var in json_encoded. Thanks

Comment: Any Update On this?